# Where am I going out of bounds?

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, c-strings, qsort

My code takes in a series of words as command line arguments and should sort them using qsort. Right now I print out the original Args however when it goes to print the Sorted args I receive a segmentation error. New to C, all advice is appreciated.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int stringCmp(const void *str1, const void *str2); //Function prototype.

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i;
  char **arr = malloc(argc * sizeof(char *));
  printf("Original Args:\n");
  for (i = 0; i < argc-1; i++){
    arr[i] = argv[i+1];
    printf("%s\n",arr[i]);
  }

  qsort(arr, argc, sizeof *arr, stringCmp);

  printf("\nSorted Args:\n");
  for (i = 0; i < argc; i++){
    printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
  }
  free (arr);
  return 0;
}

int stringCmp(const void *str1, const void *str2)
{
  strcmp(str1, str2);
}
```

Comment: You are only setting `arr[0]` to `arr[argc-2]`. So, `arr[argc-1]` might be pointing to a random location. While calling `qsort`, however, you are sending `argc` as the second parameter. You should pass `argc-1`.

Answer (score 2):

Your comparison function isn't returning anything.  Also, this function takes the address of the array elements, so what you're actually getting are `char * const *`, not `void *`

You want:

```
int stringCmp(const void *str1, const void *str2)
{
  const char * const *s1 = str1;
  const char * const *s2 = str2;
  return strcmp(*s1, *s2);
}
```

You're also not passing in the correct number of elements to `qsort`.  It should be `argc-1`, not `argc`.  The same going for printing the list:

```
  qsort(arr, argc-1, sizeof *arr, stringCmp);

  printf("\nSorted Args:\n");
  for (i = 0; i < argc-1; i++){
    printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, that would definitely help. I did make that adjustment, but still getting Segmentation fault error.

Answer (score 2):

For starters you are passing invalid number of elements

```
qsort(arr, argc, sizeof *arr, stringCmp);
```

You need to write

```
qsort(arr, argc - 1, sizeof *arr, stringCmp);
```

Secondly the function `stringCmp` returns nothing and uses incorrect arguments in the call of `strcmp`. It should look like

```
int stringCmp(const void *str1, const void *str2)
{
  return strcmp( *( const char ** )str1, *( const char ** )str2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vlad! Ill have to check out some more tutorials explaining pointers and what the "*" symbol does in C

Answer (score 1):

out by one here too

```
for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
}
```

should be

```
for (i = 0; i < argc - 1; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Im also having an issue getting with my comparison method. I got it to output the strings in alphabertical order. Now I'm trying to get the output to sort strings by their lengths.                                                                                                
```int stringCmp(const void *str1, const void *str2)
{
  return strlen(str1) - strlen(str2);
  // return strcmp(*(char **)str1,*(char**) str2);
}```
This prints them out in reverse order, not by string length. Am I doing something wrong with pointers?

Comment: @Looprachaun different question, pleas post a new question, or update the original